# BASH and jq to access JSON key-value pair

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, jq

How can I access the key and value in BASH and/or jq?

I have a command shown below:

```
asg_name="bleh"
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups \
    --auto-scaling-group-names $asg_name | 
    jq -r '.AutoScalingGroups[].Instances[] | 
           {InstanceId: .InstanceId, HealthStatus: .HealthStatus, LifecycleState: .LifecycleState}'
```

which produces the following format:

```
{
  "InstanceId": "i-jibberish",
  "HealthStatus": "Healthy",
  "LifecycleState": "InService"
}
{
  "InstanceId": "i-jibberish",
  "HealthStatus": "Healthy",
  "LifecycleState": "InService"
}
```

How can I extract the value of each key in each JSON block (as the same row) so that I can use it in another process? Similar to the following effect:

```
for obj in $results
do
   if [ obj[ValueOfHealthStatus] = "Healthy" ] && [ obj[ValueLifeCycleState] = "InService" ]; then
      do_something(obj[ValueOfInstanceId])   
   fi
done
```

Is it possible at all?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is all possible and you can even do all the logic inside jq iteself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implemented as Bash logic:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

jq -s -j '.[]|(.InstanceId + "\u001f" + .HealthStatus + "\u001f" + .LifecycleState, "\u0000")' a.json |
while IFS=$'\37' read -r -d '' InstanceId HealthStatus LifecycleState; do
  if [ "$HealthStatus" == 'Healthy' ] && [ "$LifecycleState" == 'InService' ]; then
    echo do_something "$InstanceId"
  fi
done
```

Implemented as `jq` logic:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

jq -sj '.[]|if .HealthStatus=="Healthy" and .LifecycleState=="InService" then .InstanceId + "\u0000" else empty end' a.json |
while IFS= read -r -d '' InstanceID; do
  echo do_something "$InstanceID"
done
```

**EDIT**
Forgot about `jq` `select` which is even more appropriate here than an `if then else empty end`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

jq -sj '.[] | select(.HealthStatus == "Healthy" and .LifecycleState == "InService") | .InstanceId + "\u0000"' a.json |
while IFS= read -r -d '' InstanceID; do
  echo do_something "$InstanceID"
done
```

Comment: @absolutelynewbie I added jq `select` method I missed earlier. `select` is more appropriate to filter elements of an array than `if then .foo else empty end`.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @Léa Gris. My initial take was using the BASH solution as I know more about BASH than jq but in the end I chose the previous version of the jq solution because it looks simpler. I like your update. It even looks less cluttering and more elegant. I'll update my code using the `select` construct. Thank you very much